# Manuals for Nintendo 64

Tags: nintendo-64

I have my dad's old n64, and a bunch of games for it. I have some of the manuals, and that's very helpful, but I'm missing a lot of them as well. Is there a site where I can find and download free official PDF files for old n64 games?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have the link to the manual for the console itself:

https://archive.org/details/Nintendo_64_Instruction_Booklet_1996_Nintendo_US/page/n23

And here you can download some game manuals:

[https://www.nintendo.co.uk/Support/Nintendo-64/Nintendo-64-manual-and-additional-documents/Nintendo-64-games-manuals/Nintendo-64-games-manuals-990819.html](https://archive.org/details/Nintendo_64_Instruction_Booklet_1996_Nintendo_US/page/n23)

I can't seem to find US manuals for the games but hopefully, those work for you